# connection to NodeJs and Express.io get error

Tags: java, android, ios, node.js, sockets

i'm newbie in nodejs and express.io , in android application i'm wrote this simple code to connect from android or java but iget connection error

```
app = require('express.io')()
app.http().io()

// Broadcast the new visitor event on ready route.
app.io.route('ready', function(req) {
    req.io.broadcast('new visitor')
    console.log('ready');
})

// Send client html.
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    //res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client.html')
  req.io.broadcast('new visitor')
  console.log('hello');
})

app.listen(7076)
```

this code maybe is correct, after opening `http://192.168.1.5:7076` link in browser i get `hello` message, now with below code i'm try to connect but i get connection error:

```
private static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://192.168.1.5:7076";
private Socket mSocket;
{
    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket(SERVER_ADDRESS);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        Log.e("Error URI", String.valueOf(e));
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
public class ActivityHome extends FragmentActivity {
    ...
    mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
    mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectError);
    mSocket.on("new message", onNewMessage);
    mSocket.on("user joined", onUserJoined);
    mSocket.on("user left", onUserLeft);
    mSocket.on("typing", onTyping);
    mSocket.on("stop typing", onStopTyping);
    mSocket.connect();
    ...
}

private Emitter.Listener onConnectError = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "CONNECT ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: any more detailed info about an error? This is ment to be a http server for serving web content, or a socket server? Or both? Any more information about what would you like to achieve?

Comment: @yergo my problem solved sir, thanks can i get you mail address?

Comment: please provide us solution for your problem as your own, accepted answer in that case. You can mail me by: stack at yergo.nazwa.pl